# Hyperlink Not Found in Yii2

Tags: hyperlink, yii2, href, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to create link in `views/buku/index.php`. And I want to redirect to page `views/buku/utama.php`. I'm using this code:

```
<?= Html::a('Link', ['/buku/utama']) ?>
```

But when I click "Link", I'm getting an error: `Page Not Found`. What is the solution?. (Solved)

Comment: I've created a method in the controller, but when I click "Link" I find a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function in your `BukuController`:

```
public function actionUtama() {
   return $this->render('utama');
}
```

Your link should be:

```
<?= Html::a(Yii::t('app','Link'),['buku/utama']); ?>
```